# Prove $ g \mid f $ and $ f \mid g \iff $ when $ f = c \cdot g $

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $ f, g \in F[x] $, where $ F $ is a field. Prove that,  $ g \mid f $ and $ f \mid g \iff $ when $ f = c \cdot g $ for $ c \in F^*$.
I don't know nothing about it, so I please at help.

Comment: Don't let the polynomial ring confuse you. This is true in any integral domain.

Comment: Well, you need to have the definitions of all the concepts not only at your fingertip but in the most active part of your brain. Then it falls out. Make sure you know how degree behaves under multiplication, and what the elements of degree zero are.

Comment: But, @Tomas, what takes the place of “$c\in F^*$”?

Comment: @Lubin: Agreed. The general statement would be for $f,g\in R$ where $R$ is an integral domain: $$g\mid f,f\mid g\Leftrightarrow \exists c\in R^*: f=cg$$ This agrees with this task, since $F[X]^*=F^*$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: If $g\mid f$, then there is some $h\in F[x]$ such that $f=gh$. Note that if $f=0$, then $g=0=1\cdot f$, so we may as well assume that $f\ne 0$. Similarly, if $f\mid g$, then there is some $k\in F[x]$ such that $g=fk$. Thus, $f=gh=fkh$, and $kh=1_F$. What does tell you about the polynomials $k$ and $h$?

Comment: Could you remind me, what does it mean $ kh = 1_F $, because I just start learn this topic.

Comment: @Mat: $kh$ is the product of the two polynomials $k$ and $h$ in the ring $F[x]$. $1_F$ is both the multiplicative identity of $F$, which can be identified with $1_{F[x]}$, the constant polynomial $1_F$.

Comment: I understand now, thank you :).

Comment: @Mat: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $a|b$, then what does $b$ equal in terms of $a$? Try applying this to $f|g$ and $g|f$ and then combine the results.

Answer (score 1):

The case $f=0$ or $g=0$ is trivial so let's take the general case: $f,g\neq 0$.

Since $f|g$ then there's a polynomial $h$ such that $g=fh$ and Since $g|f$ then there's a polynomial $h'$ such that $f=gh'$ so by multiplying the equalities we have $hh'=1$ hence $h'$ is invertible so it's a constant $c$.

**Added** By the equality
$$\deg(fg)=\deg(f)+\deg(g)$$
we see that in the ring $F[x]$ the non zero constant polynomials are the only invertible polynomials.